# Defining an assignment operator on a custom class

Tags: c++, class

Here's a paragraph from the book "Accelerated C++":

> In the case of the assignment versions of binary operators, we want to constrain the left operand to be of the class type. Otherwise, what would happen? If we allowed conversions for the left operand, then we might convert that operand to the class type and assign a new value to the resulting temporary. Because that value would be a temporary object, once we compiled the assignment we would have no way to access the object to which we had just assigned! Therefore, like the assignment operator itself, all of the compound- assignment operators should be member of the class.

So, we are talking about a class `Str` here, which is made to be like the library class `string`.

I am unable to clearly understand what it means. Can anyone help me?

Comment: It means to say that, unlike, say, `operator+` that could be defined as a member function taking one parameter or as a non-member taking two parameters, `operator=` (and `operator+=` and so on) can only be defined as a member function, and for good reasons.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik The paragraph is telling the reason , And that's what i don't understand . So if you can share those good reasons , it would be very helpful.

Comment: Actually, I'm not quite sure what they had in mind. My understanding is this: `operator+` is allowed to be a non-member because you may want to have your class on either side: say, `1 + myMatrix` should work just as well as `myMatrix + 1`. But assignment is fundamentally asymmetric - while `myMatrix += 1` makes sense, `1 += myMatrix` does not. So `operator=` et al are always member functions of the class that appears on the left-hand side, taking right-hand side as an argument.